# pip не распознано, как имя

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

тупой вопрос, add to path нажал при установке питона( перешел на новый комп, так что решил установить питошку), а консоль выдает такое

```
pip : Имя "pip" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ pip install discord.py
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

если что, то это vscode

Comment: Path вручную проверял? Попробуй добавить и в верхний path и в нижний.

Answer (score 0):

Измени переменную среды пользователя Path, либо переустанови Python

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/641334)

Comment: @Spatz это и есть решение вопроса. Дополнять здесь нечего...

Comment: @MaximChyorny тут целый трактат можно написать. Но ответ на вопрос содержится, хоть я с ответом и не согласен. Переустановка python -> не встречал еще проблемы, чтобы была необходимость