# Имя "pip" не распознано PyCharm

Tags: python, pip

не могу программу преобразовать в .exe
pip : Имя "pip" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и
правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1

- pip install pyinstaller
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Возможно поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1322839/pip-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка установки модуля: pip не является внешней или внутренней командой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624272/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f-pip-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1):

Актуально?
Я победил у себя.
В path указан путь?(echo %PATH% в cmd)
для начала проверяем куда смотрит и видит ли там твой pycharm сам pip, для этого в терминале ide пишем  cd: и путь до твоего питона;
в моем случае это выглядит так : cd C:\Python\Python310\Scripts
и в этой директории пишем pip команду(он скорее всего ругнется) , после чего проверяем работает ли .\p - если хэлп вышел то все хорошо.
идем в cmd , где пишем : py -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
после чего ребутим pycharm  и все работает.